# How can I get a browser to output through a non-screen channel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, arduino

Google Chrome and Firefox are starting to support the Gamepad API, and I've got code that turns a stock Arduino into a customizable gamepad ([UnoJoy!](http://UnoJoy.com)), so you can use it to get data from an Arduino into JavaScript. However, I'm trying to find a way to get data back into the Arduino.

Ideally, I'd like some kind of built-in USB hardware channel (like controlling the Scroll Lock keyboard LED) that can be hijacked to pass data, but [if push came to shove](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_push_comes_to_shove), being able to send data from the browser to an external client program would work (although I expect browser sandboxing to make that a difficult proposition...).  Ideally, though, something that worked with nothing more than stock, stable-branch Chrome would be super awesome, so that people could just go to a website, see what they need to do with their Arduino to modify it, then be good to go.

Is there a sort of hack that might be able to leak information from JavaScript this way?

I'm starting to think the camera API might give me some handles, but I'm looking for some other suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The Gamepad API is extending the enabled input-devices, like keyboards and mice. There is no intention to let an input device receive input itself. Why? Because it doesn't make sense.

There is an API called [Serial API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html) with which you can talk to these devices bidirectionally. A general approach to accessing hardware from Chrome can be found here in *[Accessing Hardware Devices](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_hardware.html)*. This is very Google/Chromium specific, and as far as I am aware of, it hasn't landed at the [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium), so it's subject to rapid change if and when it does land at the W3C.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will achieve your goal without either using a browser plugin or some program that would be run on your local computer and act as a proxy.

You could for example write a program that users would download and run on their computers and that program would have a Web interface accessible from their browser as `http://localhost:3000/` or something like that. That program could access Arduino in any way you like while providing a Web interface accessible with a stock browser without plugins.

If you want to write it in JavaScript only then you can write a little [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) program using a simple Web framework like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) plus [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) and one of the libraries that can be used to talk to Arduino like [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#readme) or [firmata](https://github.com/jgautier/firmata#readme).

See also:

- [Noduino](http://semu.github.com/noduino/) - a JavaScript framework for accessing Arduino from Web applications
- [duino](https://github.com/ecto/duino#readme) - a framework for working with Arduinos in Node.js
- [arduino.js](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/arduino-js/) - JavaScript-based Arduino Uno communication
- [JavaScript: Arduino Programming on Node.js](http://weblog.bocoup.com/javascript-arduino-programming-with-nodejs/)
- [JavaScript: Arduino Servo Control Tutorial](http://weblog.bocoup.com/javascript-arduino-servo-control-tutorial/)
- [Talking to an Arduino with Node.js and Javascript](http://mobileiteration.com/post/30281418728)
- [Controlling an Arduino from Node.js](http://brandontilley.com/2012/03/02/controlling-an-arduino-from-nodejs.html)
- [Arduino and the Web using NodeJS and SerialPort2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389676/Arduino-and-the-Web-using-NodeJS-and-SerialPort2)